# Angular 4 ngform failed to retrieve the value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I created a form in angular 4, one of the field data is get from the external js file. In the js file, I do this

```
    document.getDocumentById('fieldname').value = someValue;
```

The value is populated on the screen, but when I hit the submit button and I noticed that the particular field value is empty.

This is the code how I retrieve the form value in the Angular TypeScripts.

```
 @ViewChild('f') theForm: NgForm;
     onSubmit() {
            this.fieldname = this.theForm.value.contractData.fieldname;
    }
```

Template driven

```
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
 <div
          id="contract-data"
          ngModelGroup="contractData"
          #userData="ngModelGroup">
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="fieldname">fieldname :</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="fieldname"
                  class="form-control"
                  ngModel
                  name="fieldname"
                required  [ngModel]="fieldname"
                >
              </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Thanks-in-advance

Comment: add more code please, how do you instantiate the form? reactive or template driven?

Comment: @DanielNetzer - I use the template driven method, and I have put the component code above.

Comment: where is the form tag?

Comment: @DanielNetzer - I am pretty sure the form initialisation is working okay because I have five fields in the form only the fieldname which is getting the value from external js file was not working.

Comment: @DanielNetzer - the form tag shown above.

Comment: @DanielNetzer - Could it be a known issue? Or I am missing something here.

Comment: can you attach the entire form template? what other 5 fields? and what do you mean external js?

Comment: @DanielNetzer- The others field are the same implementation. The external js, it means the external JavaScripts file. Imagine I include the JavaScripts into my Angular project in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165360/discussion-between-daniel-netzer-and-davidb).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using the Reactive form in Angular and use the FormGroup.patch to the particular input field. It works now!